# Adding DIV ID= Tags to a views table output

Tags: 7, views, theming

I know that I can do a template override to style the views output, as described [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/how-do-i-add-div-tags-to-the-output-of-a-view-list).

I've also used a template preprocess function to add a "row_classes" to a views output. This will add DIV classes, but is it possible to add IDs as well?

Could I also use the views UI for that, maybe with a rewrite?

Comment: I haven't seen one, so I have been placing views in panels to expose an ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Btw, I ended up using a rewrite in the views UI.
I added "content:nid" to the top of the fields and then used "rewrite content" on the title field to:

```
<div id="nid[nid]">[title]</div>
```

Not a perfect solution but it seemed practical to me (at least at the time of writing this) ;-)